# How to check request is axios in laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

```
export const category_load = ()=>{
return async (dispatch) => {
    await fetch('https://example.com/api/user/categorylist')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

}

I sent the axios request to the server.
Here is the server code.

```
...
if($request->ajax()){
   return $Categories;
}
return view(Route::currentRouteName(), compact('Categories'));
```

If I sent ajax it returns $Categories but I sent axios it returns view.
I have to check axios request like ajax and return $Categories.
How to solve this?

Comment: why are you returning view for the API endpoint? Simply return ``$Categories;`` instead of  ``return view(Route::currentRouteName(), compact('Categories'));``

Comment: Because it is not used for the only API.

Comment: API endpoints are not meant to be used to return views. :) Use non API endpoints

Comment: If I sent a request using axios, it returns HTML code. :(
So I thought it returns view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API endpoints are not meant to be used to return views. :) Use non API endpoints to return views.

BTW, with your current implementation you can do this way:

Send an extra parameter, for example, `api=true` with your Axios request endpoint, as:

```
export const category_load = ()=>{
return async (dispatch) => {
    await fetch('https://example.com/api/user/categorylist?api=true')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Now, in your controller, you can check if the `api` parameter is set or not. If it's set you can just return the categories like you're doing for the ajax request, as:

```
// return $Categories if the request is from Axios or Ajax
if($request->ajax() || $request->api == true) {
   return $Categories;
}
return view(Route::currentRouteName(), compact('Categories'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it, but I used axios with your url.
If I use fetch, it returns an error.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer will work, but it's insecure what if someone gets to know why are you using the additional param and they use it on the browser direct?

Instead, pass header which by default Laravel will read to check if the incoming request is ajax or not.

```
axios.get(url, {
   body:{},
   headers: {
     "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
   },
 })
```

Now you can simply do `$request->ajax()` in the controller and it will work.